# How to translate date in spanish?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need to convert this date: 1443729984884

in this date: 01 octubre 2015 22:06

Is there a way to do this with the filters in angular ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Angular supports `i18n` Standard for location | globalization | internationalization.  When it comes to number or date formatting Angular relies on `$locale` service. 
Here is the list of locations currently supported by angular:

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n/

Here is an example on how to support [spanish locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

**[Online Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4vXdSQKjSlUwUauok6iK?p=preview)**

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>

   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_es-es.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body >
     <span ng-non-bindable>{{1443729984884 | date:'dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm'}}</span>:
     <span>{{1443729984884 | date:'dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm'}}</span><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JoseAnibalRodriguez please it helps you don't forget to up vote tit