# How to format date to German in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, date, localization, format

how can I convert the day (EEEE) into German in AngularJS? Example: Monday to Montag

My code:

```
<div class="item item-divider">{{item.date | date:"EEEE dd.MM.yyyy"}} {{item.hours}}</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896619/3646958 I just included the german locale js-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to include the appropriate locale script:

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
   …
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <!-- add this line: -->
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
   …
 </head>
</html>
```

More info here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n